# mysql - How to mysqli_query select a value like in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

What I'm trying to do is, for example:
I have a string, that I use as an array with explode:

```
$string = "Hello Cruel World";
$string = $explode(' ', $string);
```

How could I use the values `$string[0]`, `$string[1]`, as a `mysqli_query()` `select` like? For exemple: `content LIKE $string[0] OR $string[1]`....

But the `$string` value could be anything, so I need to have the size of the array too.
It there a way to do this? To `select LIKE` from an `array`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please add some content to your question, what have you tried so far? SO is not here to code for you, but to help on specific problematics. Thank you

Comment: Hint: use a for loop to create your where string, and remove the $ from "explode".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = 'Hello Cruel World';
$parts = explode(' ', $string);
$escaped = array();
foreach($parts as $part) {
    $escaped[] = mysql_real_escape_string($part);
}
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE yourfield IN ('" . implode("','", $escaped) . "');";
```

which should produce

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE yourfield IN ('Hello','Cruel','World')
```

For wildcarded LIKE comparisons

```
    $escaped[] = "yourfield LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($part) . "%'";

$sql = "... WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $escaped);
```

giving

```
  ... WHERE yourfield LIKE '%Hello%' OR yourfield LIKE '%Cruel%' OR yourfield LIKE '%World%'
```

Comment: Should $quoted be $escaped instead?